# Pedir Senha ao Entra na Página

Tags: php, html

Bom, Eu tenho uma Página e quero protegê-la,
Mas com htaccess, tudo no diretório fica fechado. Eu só quero pedir uma Senha e Nome de Usuário para entrar nela, não nas outras coisas no diretório.

Aqui está o código que eu já consegui nela:

```
<?php
  $pagina = "content.html";
  if(isset($_POST)){
    if($_POST["conteudo"]){
      $fopen = fopen($pagina,"w+");
      fwrite($fopen,$_POST["conteudo"]);
      fclose($fopen);
    }
  }
?>
<head>
<title>Edit Content Modal</title>
</head>
<br>
<br><br><br>
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="conteudo" style="height: 400px; width: 800px; border: none; margin-left: 27%;" placeholder="Type Here the Code..."><?= file_get_contents($pagina); ?></textarea>
  <br><br><input style="margin-left: 50%;" type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
</form>
```

Eu quero colocar só uma Senha nessa página (Ela vai servir para editar outra).
Mas só nela, não no diretório inteiro.
Creio que a senha precisa ser armazenada em um arquivo PHP para ninguém descobri-la.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
class Authenticator {

  public static $username = "hugo";
  public static $password = "1234";

  public static function check() {
    if (
      isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) &&
      isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) &&
      $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == self::$username &&
      $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == self::$password
    ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Please login."');
      header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
      die("Usuário ou senha incorretos!");
    }
  }

}

if(Authenticator::check()){
  echo "Você tem acesso ao conteúdo!";
  $pagina = "content.html";
  if(isset($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST["conteudo"])){
      $fopen = fopen($pagina,"w+");
      fwrite($fopen,$_POST["conteudo"]);
      fclose($fopen);
    }
  }
}
else return null;
?>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<title>Edit Content Modal</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="conteudo" style="height: 400px; width: 800px; border: none; margin-left: 27%;" placeholder="Type Here the Code..."><?= file_get_contents($pagina); ?></textarea>
  <br><br><input style="margin-left: 50%;" type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como definir a senha e o usuário correto?

Comment: Atualizei dá uma olhada agora...

Comment: No caso eu defini o usuário como hugo e a senha como 1234

Comment: Obrigado :) Vou testar.

Comment: Eu testei, mas dá nisso:

Comment: Strict Standards: Non-static method Authenticator::check() should not be called statically in /home/u146117321/public_html/news/index.php on line 25

Strict Standards: Non-static method Authenticator::check() should not be called statically in /home/u146117321/public_html/news/index.php on line 40

Comment: Funcionou??????

Comment: Eu testei aqui e funcionou de boa :)

Comment: Estou tentando corrigir o código

Comment: Pega minha resposta! Eu já atualizei e corrigi pra você!

Comment: Obrigado :) Parece que consertou mesmo.

Comment: Você pode aprender mais sobre isso aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Apenas cuidado no uso desses cabeçalhos pois dependendo do browser são ignorados e o usuário consegue acessar livremente. Em alguns casos permanece bloqueado mesmo inserindo login e senha corretos.

Comment: Yep e pode usar funções hash nas senhas tbm.